# How do I globally address a Microsoft Graph driveItem?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

DriveItems only seem to be accessible by ID if you know which drive it resides in.

What's the best way to globally identify a DriveItem?
e.g a URN that can be used with the C# graph SDK?

Preferably one way that will work with Sharepoint, Teams and OneDrive for business

Comment: for graph api, [drive item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) can only be reached by path or id

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL of the drive item, you can encode the URL and use `shares` endpoint.

Encoding URL:

```
var stringData = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/{path_to_file}";
var byteData = stringData.getBytes();
var base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteData);

var sharedDriveItem = await graphClient.Shares[$"{base64String}"]
    .DriveItem
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Not sure if it's useful in your case.

Resources:

[Accessing drivItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks I had seen this but wasn't sure if it was appropriate - do you know if using sharing links is reliable? e.g. do they expire? I see it requires ReadWrite permission so I guess it changes the document - perhaps this will not be appropriate for my needs.

Comment: @JanMartin I think that created links do not expire unless a default expiration policy is enforced for the organization. When creating sharing links you can specify expirationDateTime. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body